# render a full web page in node.js code

Tags: html, node.js

I am running a node.js server, and it is rendering a web page wonderfully. When I look at this in a browser, it runs exactly as I expect.

However, what I actually want to do is make the call to fully generate the html page - exactly as it is in the browser - within the node.js code, as a call. Currently, I have tried this:

```
http.request("http://localhost:8000/").end();
```

(with a few variants). This does exactly what it says, which is to make the single call to the server for the page - what it doesn't do is actually render the page, pulling in all of the other script files, and running the code on the page.

I have tried exploring express and ejs, and I think I need to use one of these, but I cannot find out how to do this fairly straightforward task. All it needs is to render an html page, but it seems to be a whole lot more complex than it should be.

Comment: "All it needs is to render an html page, but it seems to be a whole lot more complex than it should be." -- I think your expectations are way off, rendering a web page is an incredibly complex process.  Try searching for "mechanize-js" and "zombie" to get an idea of the complexity.

Comment: Nodejs isn't a browser. What exactly do you want to do? Are you looking to load a remote page and send to connecting browsers, Like a proxy?

Comment: I am aware that a browser is complex - what I meant is that the idea of simply rendering a page feels like it should be easy. Yes, I know nodejs isn't a browser, I am looking for something like a proxy, to render pages on the server, to send finished pages to the client. All of the evidence does indicate that this seems like a thing to do. In essence, I want to call up www.google.com (not actually, but for example), and get the page to render fully as if I were calling from a browser. That is all (!!). It seems like something that some node developer should have answered somewhere!

Comment: So are you looking to create a proxy or actually implement a web browser on the server?

Comment: I am looking to render a page on the server, the results of which I will then use.

Comment: Check out [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

Comment: What is your definition of the word **render** ?

Comment: parse - run the html and js on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What output do you want? A string of HTML? Maybe you want PhantomJS the headless browser. You could use it to render the page, then get the rendered DOM as a string of HTML.

Comment: This was the closest I got to making it work. In the end, we went down a different route - equally crazy, but seems to be working better. I don't make the rules, sadly.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat what did you end up doing?

Comment: @Alex - I split the processing to keep the rendering on the browser, and the processing that I could on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Mikeal's [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module to make http requests once you captured the response you  then can inspect the html however you like.

To make that easier though you should use [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio), this will give you a jQuery style api to manipulate the html.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)?

In a nutshell, it will render an entire web page (including images and JavaScript) to a PDF document.